# How to add multiple events in one tag?

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a counting timer which is described below with this react functional component

```
import {useEffect, useState, useRef} from 'react'

function Content() {
   
    const [countdown, setCountdown] = useState(10)
    const [show, setShow] = useState(true)

    const ref = useRef()

    function handleStart() {
        ref.current = setInterval(() => {
            setCountdown(prev => prev - 1)
        }, 1000)
    }
    function handleStop() {
        clearInterval(ref.current)
    }
 

    return (
        <div>
            <h2 style={{padding: 20}}>Time remaining: {countdown}</h2>
            <button onClick={handleStart}>Start</button>
            <button onClick={handleStop}>Stop</button>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Content;
```

How do I hide these two buttons after clicking one of the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `show` is the variable to control whether the buttons are visible or not.

```js
<div>
   <h2 style={{padding: 20}}>Time remaining: {countdown}</h2>
   {show && <>
      <button onClick={() => {
         setShow(false)
         handleStart()
}}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={() => {
         setShow(false)
         handleStop()
}}>Stop</button>
   </>}
</div>
```

React children need to return one element, so you can either wrap it in a div, or an empty element, <> </>, so you can return multiple nodes without adding a div, span, etc.

`show && <></>` means if `show` is true, the right-hand side will render, otherwise, it won't be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to introduce new state variable, you need one ror the start btn and another for the stop btn.

You have to `setShow` to false on either click and render the buttons conditionally depending on `show` variable:

```
const [countdown, setCountdown] = useState(10)
const [showStart, setShowStart] = useState(true)
const [showStop, setShowStop] = useState(true);

const ref = useRef()

function handleStart() {
    setShowStart(false);

    ref.current = setInterval(() => {
        setCountdown(prev => prev - 1)
    }, 1000)
}
function handleStop() {
    setShowStop(false);

    clearInterval(ref.current)
}


return (
    <div>
        <h2 style={{padding: 20}}>Time remaining: {countdown}</h2>
        {showStart && <button onClick={handleStart}>Start</button>}
        {showStop && <button onClick={handleStop}>Stop</button>}
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the Below Code Solver Your Problem

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [countdown, setCountdown] = useState(10);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  const ref = useRef();

  function handleStart() {
    setShow(!show);
    ref.current = setInterval(() => {
      setCountdown((prev) => prev - 1);
    }, 1000);
  }
  function handleStop() {
    setShow(!show);
    clearInterval(ref.current);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 style={{ padding: 20 }}>Time remaining: {countdown}</h2>
      {show && (
        <div>
          <button onClick={handleStart}>Start</button>
          <button onClick={handleStop}>Stop</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Example;
```